# Issue with amp-list not displaying all items

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

We have a page which has a amp-list bound to JSON data to display the subcategories of a category. In one instance it displays all the sub categories, but in another the amp-list doesn't resize to display all the items (unless you click or interact with them in some way).

Working: https://www.caresuperstore.com/kitchen-and-dining/kitchen-aids-ampd  (13 items)

Not working: https://www.caresuperstore.com/bathroom/bathing-aids-ampd (shows 6 but actually has 12)

This only seems to happen when viewing it on desktop.

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: for bathing, i see 12; first is bath boards, last is swivel bath seat. Same on desktop and mobile.

Comment: @JayGray - yes you can see 12 now, as we removed the footer from the site completely - this seems to fix it? Very strange.